# Add column to count records for unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I'm dealing with data regarding people who have visited a certain place. Each person has their own unique `PersonID` and each of their visits has a unique `VisitID`. What I'd like to do is add a column to my query that counts the number of distinct records for each person (i.e. counts and displays the number of times that person visited). The logic makes sense in my head, but I'm unsure about syntax, and the similar questions I've looked at while researching just haven't quite applied to my situation.

So here's what I'm looking at:

```
SELECT
    PersonID,
    [a few other demographic fields we'll skip for now],
    VisitID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT VisitID) as PersonVisits

FROM VisitInfo
WHERE VisitID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY PersonID, VisitID
```

And I'm hoping to see results like this:

```
PersonID   ...    VisitID      PersonVisits
------------------------------------------------
1001       ...    0277         2
1001       ...    1429         2
1002       ...    1103         1
1003       ...    0925         3
1003       ...    2276         3
1003       ...    5018         3
```

I know the `PersonVisits` count would just repeat for each of a given person's records, but that's something I can deal with for the purposes of this project (unless anyone has any suggestions for how to improve that aspect of the query).

My main problem is that

1. I'm not sure if what I'm doing is even the correct way to go about this

and

2. As it stands now, this query is giving me the error that

> Column PersonID is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY function.

I wasn't getting that error until I added the COUNT function to the select list.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: The PatientID is not in your select, so is it one of the other columns you've excluded from your example?
Also if you want to join the 'Person' together so you don't get multiple PersonVisit rows you can just add a `GROUP BY PersonID`

Comment: Ah, shoot, that should be PersonID. I'm working on two different things and mixed them up. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use aggregates in SQL (sum, count, etc), you need a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    PersonID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT VisitID) as PersonVisits

FROM VisitInfo
WHERE VisitID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY PersonID
ORDER BY PersonID
```

As a rule of thumb, ALL non-aggregated columns in your `SELECT` need to be in the `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
    PersonID,
    [a few other demographic fields we''ll skip for now],
    VisitID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT VisitID) as PersonVisits

FROM VisitInfo
WHERE VisitID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY     
PersonID,
    [a few other demographic fields we'll skip for now],
    VisitID,
ORDER BY PersonID, VisitID
```

This is probably going to give you weird/incorrect results since your query is most likely going to introduce duplicates and be grouped very tightly due to the values in your `SELECT`

Comment: I *think* this will end up doing the trick. It works like a charm if I just stick to the `PersonID` and `COUNT` function in the select list, but you're right, adding a bunch of other columns to the `GROUP BY` will likely mess things up. I may end up having to just pull the rest of the demographic info in once I've got everything set up in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option is the window function `sum() over()`

```
SELECT  PersonID,
        VisitID,
        PersonVisits = sum(1) over (partition by PersonID)
FROM VisitInfo
WHERE VisitID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY PersonID, VisitID
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to a query which groups by PersonID and returns the number of distinct VisitIDs for each one of them:

```
SELECT
    t.PersonID,
    t.col1, t.col2, ...,
    t.VisitID,
    g.PersonVisits
FROM VisitInfo t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT PersonID, COUNT(DISTINCT VisitID) PersonVisits
  FROM VisitInfo
  GROUP BY PersonID 
) g ON g.PesronID = t.PersonID
WHERE t.VisitID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t.PersonID, t.VisitID
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I would write it...

```
    select person_id, demo1, demo2, demo3, count(distinct visitid) as visits
    from visitinfo
    where visitid is not null
    group by 1,2,3,4
    order by 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Thats not valid for SQL Server, you can't group by a column index. And its recommended best practice not to use that method for order by as its very unclear what is happening.